# Java JsonPath grab InvalidPathException in code

Tags: java, json, exception, jsonpath

I am using JsonPath and am able to parse my data and get the values when the path provided is correct.

However when I provide an incorrect path (user input) the program terminates. I dont want that to happen. Is there anyway for me to catch this exceptions and continue with the next steps?

```
try
        {
            String value = JsonPath.read(jsonText, jsonPath);

            System.out.println(value);
        }
        catch(InvalidPathException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR<InvalidPathException>: "+e.getMessage());
        }
```

I get following error with invalid path:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: invalid path
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.filter.FieldFilter.filter(FieldFilter.java:59)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:182)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:202)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:307)
at office.jsonPathparse.main(jsonPathparse.java:37)
```

This exception seems to be comming from FieldFilter which is jar's class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly and your catch block isn't being executed, you must be catching Java 7's `java.nio.file.InvalidPathException` instead of `JsonPath`'s `com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException`.

Double check your `import` statements.

Comment: Thank you @Sotirios .. I din realise I imported incorrect exception .. 
My code is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Library arises invalid path exception on basis of below code`(taken from grepcode)`

```
if (jsonPath == null || jsonPath.trim().isEmpty() || jsonPath.matches("new ") 
       || jsonPath.matches("[^\\?\\+\\=\\-\\*\\/\\!]\\(")) {

       throw new InvalidPathException("Invalid path");

 }
```

So i think you should print jsonPath and matches it with the above condition.